# Put get parameters into post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am submitting a form via an ajax post request but there is a possibility that there is also one get parameter and if the get parameter is set it must be included in the post request.
I currently have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#plugin_check").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: actionUrl,
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
          $("#result").html(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });
  });  
});
```

I need to figure out how to put $_GET['datesort'] into the post data.

Comment: Assuming your GET[datesort] is when you first `get` the page, then, when you build your HTML, include an `<input type='hidden'` with the value set to your `datesort`.  If the input is in the form then it will be included in the POST data.   Alternatively, when you build the html, add it as a js variable and add that variable to the POST data manually.

Comment: Hi, putting an <input type='hidden'> into the form would be a good solution, sadly I cannot do that because I can not have php inside of the page but only behind the ajax request.
I would love to add it as a js variable and then adding the variable to the POST data manually but I don't know how and I would love a hint on that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, create variable to save datesort and add this to ajax data

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#plugin_check").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    var datesort = urlParams.get('datesort')

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: actionUrl,
      data: form.serialize() + `&datesort=${datesort}`, // serializes the form's elements.
      success: function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data); // show response from the php script.
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to put it into the url but in the POST data

Comment: @Benni sorrt, i will edit my answer

Comment: thank you for your answer, I thought it was wrong however when editing the actionUrl I can access the data via $_GET so this works.
However the variable get sadly is empty

Comment: I cannot use php on the page since this is on a wordpress page and embedded into a elementor html element

Comment: @Benni, how about that ? get url params from js